# In Excel, how do I conditionally format a cell after matching two distinct values across two separate worksheets?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, timeline, gantt-chart

I was provided a spreadsheet with a list of emails that have been sent from my company. I would like to create a visual timeline to show the days on which these emails were sent (a Gantt chart of sorts, though the duration is only one day for every task).

The worksheet, named Email List, includes a table: Column A has list of Email titles (simply named Email), and Column E has the Date (simply named Date) it was sent (there are many other columns, but these are the only two I need to reference).

I have created a separate worksheet named Visual Timeline with Column A including the email titles (same information as Column A in the Email List worksheet), and across the top, Row 5 has every date for the entire year, starting in column B.

I need to do this: Wherever Column A matches in both worksheets, look at Column E (Date) in the Email List worksheet. Use that date to color the cell in the Visual Timeline worksheet where the name and date of the email intersect.

I do not currently have Power Query installed, and do not know if this is an option.

I have tried this: `=INDEX('Email List'!A6:A9,MATCH('Email List'!E10,'Visual Timeline'!5:5,0))`but I'm just returning the date that the email was sent. I guess any returned data can be used to conditionally format the cell,but I could not figure out how to make this formula  work across the entire spreadsheet.

I've attached screenshots for visual reference:

[image: Visual Timeline Worksheet]

[image: Email List Worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with conditional formatting.

I suggest you start with a worksheet formula that will evaluate to a result that works for conditional formatting. Then use that formula in conditional formatting.

Make sure that the values in row 5 in the top screenshot are real dates, not just the numbers 1 to 31. You can still format them to just show the day of the month, but they need to be dates for the following formula to work.

It seems that the same email subject can appear multiple times. You therefore need a unique key to look up an email for a specific date. In the spreadsheet of your second screenshot, create a helper column that concatenates the email subject and the date. Something like this:

```
=A10&E10
```

Let's assume this formula is in column Z, copied down.

Now you can click cell B6 in your timeline sheet and enter this formula

```
=match($A6&B$5,'Email list'!$Z:$Z,0)
```

Note the placement of the $ signs to always refer to column A and to row 5. Copy down all email rows and across to the other days.
If the combination of email subject and date exists in the email list, a number will be returned, else the #N/A error will show.

Once that is working, select B6 in the timeline sheet, add a conditional format that uses a formula and use exactly the formula from above. It is important that you select B6 to make the relative references work with the correct cells.

Any error returned by the formula will be treated as a FALSE return, any number will be treated like a TRUE.

In the Conditional Formatting Manager dialog, apply the formula to the desired cells by setting the "Applies to" range. Or copy B6 and use Paste Special > Formats to copy the format to other cells.

You should now see the conditional formatting be applied and you can remove the formulas from the worksheet cells.

Comment: This worked great! Except I've noticed something in my data that I need to account for in addition to what I've written above. While the 'Email Column' shows the Email List that we contacted, the 'Subject Line' column (Column C in the Email List worksheet) may be different, when two different emails were sent to the same list on the same day. Can I account for this in my conditional formatting? Meaning... if there are multiples of emails sent to the same list in one day with different sbjct lines, I can color it a different color? I don't want to list every subject line in the Visual Timeline.

Comment: Yes. Instead of a Match, which only returns the first result, you could do a Countifs with the parameters for email list and date. The Countifs will return either a 0, a 1, or a higher number. Based on that number you can build one format for a 1 and another conditional format for a result greater than 1.